# Fixing colors in XCygwin emacs

Tags: emacs, cygwin, emacs23

I am using Emacs 23 in Cygwin with X, and the colours are nothing like they should be...e.g. in color-theme-gray30, the background is chocolate brown rather than gray30. I suspect I might have to export some setting in the Cygwin BAT file, but can't find out what it should be...any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is a problem with Emacs or Cygwin.  I think it may be a problem with how your monitor is adjusted (or even the angle your are viewing it from if it is an LCD).

Emacs uses the same color references as X11 (found in rgb.txt). I did a quick check with a reference page ([enter link description here](http://sedition.com/perl/rgb.html)) vs. my Emacs 23 in X11 under Cygwin, and the colors do match.  It isn't "chocolate brown" with my normal monitor setup, but I can change its tint by playing with the color controls on the monitor.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is the answer -- NT emacs on the same box looks fine.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your rgb.txt file isn't damaged?  That would do it.   Another long shot is that you are running Cygwin X full screen and using a very low color depth. (see http://x.cygwin.com/docs/man1/XWin.1.html)